# Como limpio los tags html de una string?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online

Me encontre con el problema de los tags HTML al interno de una String, la string la tomo desde un RTE-field de SharePoint :

```
var clientContext;
var list;
var item;

SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', sharePointReady);

   // Create an instance of the current context.
function sharePointReady() {
   clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
   list = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle("Prova Scheda");
   var itemId = parseInt(GetUrlKeyValue('ID'))
   item = list.getItemById(itemId);
   clientContext.load(item);
   clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onRequestSucceeded, onRequestFailed);
}
function onRequestSucceeded() {
   var corpo = item.get_item('Corpo');
   var corpoOr = item.get_item('CorpoOriginale');
   corpoOr = corpoOr.replace("<p>", "").replace("<div>", " ").replace("<br>", "\n").replace("<html>", " ").replace("</p>", "").replace("</div>", "").replace("</html>", "");
corpo = corpo.replace("<p>", "").replace("<div>", " ").replace("<br>", "\n").replace("<html>", " ").replace("</p>", "").replace("</div>", "").replace("</html>", "");
console.log(corpo + " " + corpoOr);
}
function onRequestFailed(sender, args) {
   console.log('Error: ' + args.get_message());
}´
```

al tomar la variable "corpo" me devuelve una String con los Tags html al interno, prove con : `corpo.textContent`, `corpo.innerText` y `corpo.outerHtml` pero en los 3 casos me devuelve un valor indefinido.

en el codigo que puse, como pueden ves estoy utilizando el `replace()` pero igualmente me devuelve tags html como pueden ver en el screenshot [image: Screenshot]
como limpiar todos los tags y dejar unicamente el testo ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Podrías usar una expresión regular:

```
var texto = '<p>Elemento con etiquetas <strong>que quiero</strong> que desaparezcan</p>';

var sin_tags = texto.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

alert(sin_tags);
```

En Jquery existe la función stripHTML() que se dedica a hacerte el trabajo. Pero esta es la solución que veo más sencilla en Javascript.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, funciona perfectamente! la verdad que no conocia esta exprecion :)